# AWS console how to list s3 bucket content order by last modified date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing files to a S3 bucket. How can I see the newly added files? E.g. in the below pic, you can see the files are not ordered by Last modified field. And I can't find a way to do any sort on that field or any other field.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot sort on that, it is just how the UI works.

The main reason being that for buckets with 1000+ objects the UI only "knows" about the current 1000 elements displayed on the current page. And sorting them is meaningless because it would *imply* to show you the newest or oldest 1000 objects of the bucket but in fact it would just order the currently displayed 1000 objects. That would *really* confuse people and it is better to not let the user sort instead of sorting incorrectly.

Showing the actual 1000 newest or oldest objects requires you to list everything in the bucket, which takes time (minutes or hours for larger buckets) and backend requests and incurs more of a cost since `List` requests are billed. If you want to retrieve the 1000 newest or oldest you need to write code to do a full listing on the bucket or the prefix, then order all objects and then display parts of the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have code that sorts the files names using the meta.lastmodified field

```
files = []
        file_names = []
        file_modified_date = []
        for f in s3_bucket.objects.filter().all():
            file_names.append(f.key)  #get file name
            meta = f.meta.data.items() 
            lm = list(meta)[1]   #get meta last modified returns tuple
            file_modified_date.append(lm[1])   #get the date value
        files = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(file_modified_date, file_names))]   #sort
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you need to list all objects in the bucket in order to filter by `last modified date` . For example with boto3 `list_objects_v2`, each request you will get `1000 objects` [see docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html)
*Note that every 1000 request will cost `$0.00x` (depends on the region -> [see pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)). Let say you have `100,000` objects, it will cost `$0.000x` to get all these data (100 requests x 1000)

Example python codes with boto3 and import to csv:

**Get 1,000 data of the objects in a bucket, filter the 10 newest data, and export to CSV**

> This performs 1 request (max 1000 obj), if your s3 obj/data >= 1000, you won't retrieve all the data with this, see below for all object

```
import boto3
import csv

def list_obj_in_bucket(bucket, directory, total_obj):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    # remove Prefix if you're not using directory inside your bucket or you don't want to iterate specific directory
    response = client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Prefix=directory
    )

    objects = response['Contents']
    sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda obj: obj['LastModified'], reverse=True)
    newest_objects = sorted_objects[:total_obj]

    return newest_objects


def generate_csv(data):
    with open('my_10_newest_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Key', 'LastModified', 'Size']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for obj in data:
            writer.writerow({
                'Key': obj['Key'],
                'LastModified': obj['LastModified'].isoformat(),
                'Size': obj['Size']
            })


bucket = 'my-bucket'
directory = 'my-folder-inside-bucket/' # remove this and paramater in the function if you're not using folder inside your bucket
total_obj = 10

list_of_objects = list_obj_in_bucket(bucket, directory, total_obj)
generate_csv(list_of_objects)
print("OK")
```

****Get all objects in a bucket (total request depends on your total object in bucket, i use while loop here)****

```
import boto3
import csv

def list_all_obj_in_bucket(bucket, directory):
    client = boto3.client('s3')

    objects = []
    continuation_token = None
    while True:
        # remove Prefix if you're not using directory inside your bucket
        params = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Prefix': directory}
        if continuation_token:
            params['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token

        response = client.list_objects_v2(**params)

        if 'Contents' in response:
            objects.extend(response['Contents'])

        if 'NextContinuationToken' in response:
            continuation_token = response['NextContinuationToken']
        else:
            break

    return objects

def get_last_modified(objects, total_obj):
    sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda obj: obj['LastModified'], reverse=True)
    newest_objects = sorted_objects[:total_obj]

    return newest_objects

def generate_csv(data):
    with open('all_10_newest_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Key', 'LastModified', 'Size']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for obj in data:
            writer.writerow({
                'Key': obj['Key'],
                'LastModified': obj['LastModified'].isoformat(),
                'Size': obj['Size']
            })

bucket = 'my-bucket'
directory = 'my-folder-inside-bucket/'
total_obj = 10

objects = list_all_obj_in_bucket(bucket, directory)
newest_objects = get_last_modified(objects, total_obj)

generate_csv(newest_objects)
print("OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can sufficiently decrease the number of displayed objects with the "Find objects by prefix" field, the sort options become available and meaningful.